# ArgumentNullException when sending data to kinesis in ASP.NET Core 8 Web API

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-net

After upgrading my project to .NET 8.0, the call of the function `PutRecordsAsync()` from `AWSSDK.Kinesis` (3.7.300.7) results in the following error:

> System.Private.CoreLib Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'path1')    > System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
> at System.ArgumentNullException.Throw(String paramName)
> at System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2)
> at Amazon.Internal.RegionEndpointProviderV3.GetEndpointJsonSourceStream()
> at Amazon.Internal.RegionEndpointProviderV3..ctor()
> at Amazon.RegionEndpoint.get_RegionEndpointProvider()
> at Amazon.RegionEndpoint.get_InternedRegionEndpoint()
> at Amazon.RegionEndpoint.GetEndpointForService(String serviceName, GetEndpointForServiceOptions options)
> at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Auth.AWS4Signer.DetermineSigningRegion(IClientConfig clientConfig, String serviceName, RegionEndpoint alternateEndpoint, IRequest request)
> at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Auth.AWS4Signer.SignRequest(IRequest request, IClientConfig clientConfig, RequestMetrics metrics, String awsAccessKeyId, String awsSecretAccessKey)
> at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Auth.AWS4Signer.Sign(IRequest request, IClientConfig clientConfig, RequestMetrics metrics, String awsAccessKeyId, String awsSecretAccessKey)
> at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Auth.AWS4Signer.Sign(IRequest request, IClientConfig clientConfig, RequestMetrics metrics, ImmutableCredentials credentials)
> at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Auth.AbstractAWSSigner.SignAsync(IRequest request, IClientConfig clientConfig, RequestMetrics metrics, ImmutableCredentials credentials, CancellationToken token)
> at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Signer.SignRequestAsync(IRequestContext requestContext)
> at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Signer.PreInvokeAsync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
> at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Signer.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
> at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.EndpointDiscoveryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
> at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.EndpointDiscoveryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
> at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CredentialsRetriever.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
> at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
> at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
> at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
> at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
> at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorCallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
> at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.MetricsHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
> at .SendeDataToKinesis(String streamName, Int32 bufferSize)

Code:

```
var putRecordsResponse = await _kinesisClient.PutRecordsAsync(putRecordsRequest);
```

What I already checked:

- putRecordsRequest is not null and filled with valid values
- _kinesisClient is correctly initialized with credentials & configuration

With .NET 7 everything (same code, no changes) worked as expected. Does the AWS SDK support .NET 8.0 at the moment? As stated on nuget, .NET 8.0 should be supported.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/AWSSDK.Kinesis
-> .NET 8.0 .NET Core 3.1 .NET Standard 2.0 .NET Framework 3.5

Comment: Support for .NET 8 was released in the last week or so.  Its very new.  I talked to the team and they recommend that you file a bug report.

Comment: Ok, I opened https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/3110

Answer (score 0):

What is happening, is that your application tries to load the file `endpoints.json`, which can be used to override the AWS endpoint URLs.

Previous versions of the SDK used `Assembly.Location` to calculate the path to this file, but it [doesn't work](https://github.com/dotnet/corert/issues/5647) with Native AOT.

It looks like it's been fixed [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/commit/1a7dd86bb878ed4ab5eb67e78486d3ffc2e0428e) (which was supposed to come out in Core 3.7.300.7 yesterday), but the fix didn't make it into the 8.0 build of this library.

This code:

```
#if NET8_0_OR_GREATER
            string assemblyLocation = System.AppContext.BaseDirectory;
#else
            string assemblyLocation = typeof(RegionEndpointProviderV3).Assembly.Location;
#endif
```

compiles to this IL:

```
    IL_0000: ldtoken      Amazon.Internal.RegionEndpointProviderV3
    IL_0005: call         class [System.Runtime]System.Type [System.Runtime]System.Type::GetTypeFromHandle(valuetype [System.Runtime]System.RuntimeTypeHandle)
    IL_000a: callvirt     instance class [System.Runtime]System.Reflection.Assembly [System.Runtime]System.Type::get_Assembly()
    IL_000f: callvirt     instance string [System.Runtime]System.Reflection.Assembly::get_Location()
    IL_0014: stloc.0      // assemblyLocation
```

Comment: But I already used AWSSDK.Kinesis (3.7.300.7) which depends on AWSSDK.Core (>= 3.7.300.7 && < 4.0.0) (see https://www.nuget.org/packages/AWSSDK.Kinesis)

Comment: @neox2811: I just disassembled the .net8.0 version of the library. I see the conditional flag in the debug symbols, but it wasn't picked up during the compilation. So yes, it's a bug, probably somewhere in their build system.